# how to read specific values from text file using c++?

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a textfile as follows:

```
Value1 = windows
Value2 = Processor
Value3 = pwower plug
```

Right now i am retrieving complete file as follows:

```
std::ifstream myfile;
myfile.open( "D:\\values_user.txt", std::ios::in );

if( !(myfile.is_open()) )
{   std::cout << "Error Opening File";
std::exit(0);   }

std::string firstline;


while( myfile.good() )
{
    std::getline( myfile, firstline);
    std::cout<< "\n" << firstline <<"\n";
}
```

I want to  retrieve window, processor and pwower plug i.e. just want to have values after '='.
So, suggest me how can i achieve this.

Comment: Related: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125) checking `.good()` got the same problem as `.eof()`.  Prefer putting the read in the loop condition.

Answer (score -1):

Just Tokenize your string (firstline) basedd on  the delimeter character (=, in your case).

Here is the example.

[strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)